# Laravel query builder limit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crud

I've been using Laravel for a little while now and really enjoying it,however I seem to have come unstuck using the query builder.

I have multiple UNIONS in my query which is all working exactly how I'd like however when I add the ->take() method to limit my results something a little strange happens, instead of the limit sitting at the end of my query it sits inside the first select.

Example as it stands:

```
(select * FROM fruit LIMIT 1) union (select * FROM veg)
```

Example of how I'd like it to work:

```
(select * FROM fruit) union (select * FROM veg) LIMIT 1
```

BASIC CODE EXAMPLE:

```
$fruit = DB::table('fruit')
           ->select(*);

$veg = DB::table('veg')
           ->select(*);

$query = $fruit->union($veg)->take(1)->get();

return $query;
```

Has anyone suffered the same issue? More importantly has anyone managed to resolve this issue? I've been searching for hours for a resolve so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no mysql union functions in Fluent Query Builder, that union expects adds another query.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit, sorry, this won't work either, indeed the FQB doesn't know union.*

Would rather advise you building this with Eloquent, but if you want to do it this way, this might work:

```
$fruit->union($veg)->first();
```